# I mined an uncle. When do i get paid?

Tags: uncle-blocks

There doesn't seem to be an answer to this question anywhere.
Geth shows I mined an uncle.
There's all kinds of discussions about what/where/and how uncles exist,
but when does the miner get paid?

Answer (score 1):

An uncle block only exist as such when it is incoraped in a regular block.

A uncle miner is paid immediately when a regular block includes it.

Perhaps with an example is more clear

- blocks A100 and B100 are found at heigh 100
- block A101 is mined on top of A100
- block A102 includes B100 as uncle

Miner from B100 will be credited after block A102 is mined.

Comment: So the geth ledger reads like this: mined possible block

Comment: So the geth ledger reads like this: mined potential block   block became a side fork      commit new mining work number=3 txs=0 uncles=1                   payout or no payout?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with geth messages. If you have the block hash you can check in etherscan.io, if you have the miner address there's a 'Mined uncles' tab.